# How do I avoid mutation of a boolean flag in a closure?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, closures, state

Let's say I have this function in TypeScript, which uses a closure to manage state:

1. The firebase analytics instance
2. The guid (user Id).

The function returns another function that accepts the arguments for Firebase's `logEvent` method. I only want to set the user ID on firebase once, so I am using a boolean flag to check if it's been done before.

Is there a way to do this without mutating the `guidSet` variable? Or is there a way to accomplish this without a boolean flag that necessitates mutation?

I'm aware, that in something small like this, perhaps readability outweighs the "dogma" of not mutating variables. Also the fact that the `guidSet` is not observable to anything outside the `Logger` function makes this mutation less "dangerous," but regardless I'm interested in how I could accomplish this without technically mutating anything within my function:

```js
import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";

function Logger(): Function {
  const analyticsInst = analytics();
  let guidSet: boolean;
  return (key: string, data?: any, guid?: string | null) => {
    if (!guidSet && guid) {
      guidSet = true;
      analyticsInst.setUserId(guid);
    }
    analyticsInst.logEvent(key, data);
  };
}
```

Comment: You'd typically return the new Boolean value from the function. When a function already returns an 'other' value, you return a tuple. That's basically the Writer monad.

Comment: Can you expand or provide an example? If you answer I'd mark it as accepted.

Comment: I assume the closure is invoked by an event and you want `logEvent` to be invoked any number of times but `setUserId` only once. So basically you are working in an effectful, impure environment and want to avoid a single impure aspect, namely reassignment. AFAIK, this doesn't work. Your lambda doesn't even return a value. Maybe you can split both operations and assign them to different event handlers, one of which is triggered only once?

Comment: I think you are right. The lambda's purpose is a side-effect. So certainly a mutated "private" variable is, in the scheme of things, absolutely fine.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `analyticsInst.setUserId` and `analyticsInst.logEvent` look like side-effecty (i.e. *impure*) actions. As long as the `Logger` action is doing that, there's little reason to avoid the mutation of `guidSet` because the overall action would remain impure even if you could eliminate that particular mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```ts
import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";

function Logger(guid: string): Function {
  const analyticsInst = analytics();
  analyticsInst.setUserId(guid);

  return (key: string, data?: any) => {
    analyticsInst.logEvent(key, data);
  };
}
```

Comment: No, because I don't want to set the guid when calling the outer function.